# Scraping sports data using beautiful soup and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the score from the first quarter of the game on this [webpage for the home team](http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard) and my code doesn't return anything.  Here's what I have so far.  Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

first_quarter = []
#will find tr and for every the 2nd instance of td, should extract that value?
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[0:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    column_1=col[1].string.strip()
    first_quarter.append(column_1)
#adds value from 2nd instance of td and puts it under heading 'first_quarter'
columns = {'first_quarter': first_quarter}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

The content is dynamically loaded, if we do a bit of parsing we can pull the data from the source:

```
import re
import json
from pprint import pprint as pp

r = requests.get("http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard").content
scr = BeautifulSoup(r).find("script",text=re.compile("window.espn.scoreboardData")).text.split("=",1)[1].rstrip(";")
js = json.loads(scr[:scr.index(";")])
data = js["events"][0]["competitions"][0]["competitors"]

pp(data)
```

That give you a list of dicts with all the game info, rebounds, wins, losses, scores etc.. The first is the away and the second is the home so we can unpack:

```
away, home = data
```

And printing the away dict we get:

```
{u'homeAway': u'away',
 u'id': u'5',
 u'leaders': [{u'abbreviation': u'Pts',
               u'displayName': u'Points',
               u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'LeBron James',
                                          u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/1966.png',
                                          u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/1966'}],
                                          u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'SF'},
                                          u'shortName': u'L. James',
                                          u'team': {u'id': u'5'}},
                             u'displayValue': u'27',
                             u'team': {u'id': u'5'},
                             u'value': None}],
               u'name': u'points'},
              {u'abbreviation': u'Reb',
               u'displayName': u'Rebounds',
               u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'Kevin Love',
                                          u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3449.png',
                                          u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/3449'}],
                                          u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'PF'},
                                          u'shortName': u'K. Love',
                                          u'team': {u'id': u'5'}},
                             u'displayValue': u'14',
                             u'team': {u'id': u'5'},
                             u'value': None}],
               u'name': u'rebounds'},
              {u'abbreviation': u'Ast',
               u'displayName': u'Assists',
               u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'LeBron James',
                                          u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/1966.png',
                                          u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/1966'}],
                                          u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'SF'},
                                          u'shortName': u'L. James',
                                          u'team': {u'id': u'5'}},
                             u'displayValue': u'11',
                             u'team': {u'id': u'5'},
                             u'value': None}],
               u'name': u'assists'},
              {u'abbreviation': u'RAT',
               u'displayName': u'Rating',
               u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'LeBron James',
                                          u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/1966.png',
                                          u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/1966'}],
                                          u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'SF'},
                                          u'shortName': u'L. James',
                                          u'team': {u'id': u'5'}},
                             u'displayValue': u'27 PTS, 11 REB, 11 AST, 2 STL, 3 BLK',
                             u'team': {u'id': u'5'},
                             u'value': None}],
               u'name': u'rating'}],
 u'linescores': [{u'value': 23},
                 {u'value': 19},
                 {u'value': 33},
                 {u'value': 18}],
 u'records': [{u'abbreviation': u'Total',
               u'name': u'Total',
               u'summary': u'57-25',
               u'type': u'total'},
              {u'name': u'Home', u'summary': u'33-8', u'type': u'home'},
              {u'name': u'Road', u'summary': u'24-17', u'type': u'road'}],
 u'score': u'93',
 u'statistics': [{u'abbreviation': u'REB',
                  u'displayValue': u'48',
                  u'name': u'rebounds'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'RPG',
                  u'displayValue': u'48.0',
                  u'name': u'avgRebounds'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'AST',
                  u'displayValue': u'17',
                  u'name': u'assists'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'FGA',
                  u'displayValue': u'82',
                  u'name': u'fieldGoalsAttempted'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'FGM',
                  u'displayValue': u'33',
                  u'name': u'fieldGoalsMade'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'FG%',
                  u'displayValue': u'40.2',
                  u'name': u'fieldGoalPct'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'FT%',
                  u'displayValue': u'84.0',
                  u'name': u'freeThrowPct'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'FTA',
                  u'displayValue': u'25',
                  u'name': u'freeThrowsAttempted'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'FTM',
                  u'displayValue': u'21',
                  u'name': u'freeThrowsMade'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'PTS',
                  u'displayValue': u'93',
                  u'name': u'points'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'3P%',
                  u'displayValue': u'24.0',
                  u'name': u'threePointPct'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'3PA',
                  u'displayValue': u'25',
                  u'name': u'threePointFieldGoalsAttempted'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'3PM',
                  u'displayValue': u'6',
                  u'name': u'threePointFieldGoalsMade'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'PPG',
                  u'displayValue': u'93.0',
                  u'name': u'avgPoints'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'APG',
                  u'displayValue': u'17.0',
                  u'name': u'avgAssists'},
                 {u'abbreviation': u'3P%',
                  u'displayValue': u'24.0',
                  u'name': u'threePointFieldGoalPct'}],
 u'team': {u'abbreviation': u'CLE',
           u'color': u'061642',
           u'displayName': u'Cleveland Cavaliers',
           u'id': u'5',
           u'isActive': True,
           u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/cle',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'clubhouse', u'desktop', u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Clubhouse'},
                      {u'href': u'sportscenter://x-callback-url/showClubhouse?uid=s:40~l:46~t:5',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'clubhouse',
                                u'sportscenter',
                                u'app',
                                u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Clubhouse'},
                      {u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/cle',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'roster', u'desktop', u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Roster'},
                      {u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/cle',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'stats', u'desktop', u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Statistics'},
                      {u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/cle',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'schedule', u'desktop', u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Schedule'},
                      {u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/photos/_/name/cle',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'photos', u'desktop', u'team'],
                       u'text': u'photos'},
                      {u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/stadium/_/name/cle',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'stadium', u'desktop', u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Stadium'},
                      {u'href': u'http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=15528656',
                       u'isExternal': True,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'shop', u'desktop', u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Shop'},
                      {u'href': u'sportscenter://x-callback-url/showClubhouse?uid=s:40~l:46~t:5&section=scores',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': False,
                       u'rel': [u'scores',
                                u'sportscenter',
                                u'app',
                                u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Scores'},
                      {u'href': u'http://insider.espn.go.com/nbadraft/results/team/_/team/cle',
                       u'isExternal': False,
                       u'isPremium': True,
                       u'rel': [u'draftpicks', u'desktop', u'team'],
                       u'text': u'Draft Picks'}],
           u'location': u'Cleveland',
           u'logo': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nba/500/scoreboard/cle.png',
           u'name': u'Cavaliers',
           u'shortDisplayName': u'Cavaliers',
           u'uid': u's:40~l:46~t:5',
           u'venue': {u'id': u'3417'}},
 u'type': u'team',
 u'uid': u's:40~l:46~t:5',
 u'winner': True}
```

You can then get all the info you need using the keys of the dict:

```
In [49]: js = json.loads(scr[:scr.index(";")])

In [50]: data = js["events"][0]["competitions"][0]["competitors"]

In [51]: away, home = data

In [52]: away[u'score'], home["score"]
Out[52]: (u'89', u'93')

In [53]:  away["linescores"], home["linescores"]
Out[53]: 
([{u'value': 22}, {u'value': 27}, {u'value': 27}, {u'value': 13}],
 [{u'value': 23}, {u'value': 19}, {u'value': 33}, {u'value': 18}])
In [54]:  away["statistics"]
Out[54]: 
[{u'abbreviation': u'REB', u'displayValue': u'39', u'name': u'rebounds'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'RPG', u'displayValue': u'39.0', u'name': u'avgRebounds'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'AST', u'displayValue': u'22', u'name': u'assists'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'FGA',
  u'displayValue': u'83',
  u'name': u'fieldGoalsAttempted'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'FGM', u'displayValue': u'32', u'name': u'fieldGoalsMade'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'FG%', u'displayValue': u'38.6', u'name': u'fieldGoalPct'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'FT%', u'displayValue': u'76.9', u'name': u'freeThrowPct'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'FTA',
  u'displayValue': u'13',
  u'name': u'freeThrowsAttempted'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'FTM', u'displayValue': u'10', u'name': u'freeThrowsMade'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'PTS', u'displayValue': u'89', u'name': u'points'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'3P%',
  u'displayValue': u'36.6',
  u'name': u'threePointPct'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'3PA',
  u'displayValue': u'41',
  u'name': u'threePointFieldGoalsAttempted'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'3PM',
  u'displayValue': u'15',
  u'name': u'threePointFieldGoalsMade'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'PPG', u'displayValue': u'89.0', u'name': u'avgPoints'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'APG', u'displayValue': u'22.0', u'name': u'avgAssists'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'3P%',
  u'displayValue': u'36.6',
  u'name': u'threePointFieldGoalPct'}]
```

To get the top performers:

```
In [57]:  away["leaders"]
Out[57]: 
[{u'abbreviation': u'Pts',
  u'displayName': u'Points',
  u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'Draymond Green',
     u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/6589.png',
     u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/6589'}],
     u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'PF'},
     u'shortName': u'D. Green',
     u'team': {u'id': u'9'}},
    u'displayValue': u'32',
    u'team': {u'id': u'9'},
    u'value': None}],
  u'name': u'points'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'Reb',
  u'displayName': u'Rebounds',
  u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'Draymond Green',
     u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/6589.png',
     u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/6589'}],
     u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'PF'},
     u'shortName': u'D. Green',
     u'team': {u'id': u'9'}},
    u'displayValue': u'15',
    u'team': {u'id': u'9'},
    u'value': None}],
  u'name': u'rebounds'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'Ast',
  u'displayName': u'Assists',
  u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'Draymond Green',
     u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/6589.png',
     u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/6589'}],
     u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'PF'},
     u'shortName': u'D. Green',
     u'team': {u'id': u'9'}},
    u'displayValue': u'9',
    u'team': {u'id': u'9'},
    u'value': None}],
  u'name': u'assists'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'RAT',
  u'displayName': u'Rating',
  u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'Draymond Green',
     u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/6589.png',
     u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/6589'}],
     u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'PF'},
     u'shortName': u'D. Green',
     u'team': {u'id': u'9'}},
    u'displayValue': u'32 PTS, 15 REB, 9 AST, 2 STL',
    u'team': {u'id': u'9'},
    u'value': None}],
  u'name': u'rating'}]

In [58]:  home["leaders"]
Out[58]: 
[{u'abbreviation': u'Pts',
  u'displayName': u'Points',
  u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'LeBron James',
     u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/1966.png',
     u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/1966'}],
     u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'SF'},
     u'shortName': u'L. James',
     u'team': {u'id': u'5'}},
    u'displayValue': u'27',
    u'team': {u'id': u'5'},
    u'value': None}],
  u'name': u'points'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'Reb',
  u'displayName': u'Rebounds',
  u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'Kevin Love',
     u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3449.png',
     u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/3449'}],
     u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'PF'},
     u'shortName': u'K. Love',
     u'team': {u'id': u'5'}},
    u'displayValue': u'14',
    u'team': {u'id': u'5'},
    u'value': None}],
  u'name': u'rebounds'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'Ast',
  u'displayName': u'Assists',
  u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'LeBron James',
     u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/1966.png',
     u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/1966'}],
     u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'SF'},
     u'shortName': u'L. James',
     u'team': {u'id': u'5'}},
    u'displayValue': u'11',
    u'team': {u'id': u'5'},
    u'value': None}],
  u'name': u'assists'},
 {u'abbreviation': u'RAT',
  u'displayName': u'Rating',
  u'leaders': [{u'athlete': {u'displayName': u'LeBron James',
     u'headshot': u'http://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/1966.png',
     u'links': [{u'href': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/1966'}],
     u'position': {u'abbreviation': u'SF'},
     u'shortName': u'L. James',
     u'team': {u'id': u'5'}},
    u'displayValue': u'27 PTS, 11 REB, 11 AST, 2 STL, 3 BLK',
    u'team': {u'id': u'5'},
    u'value': None}],
  u'name': u'rating'}]
```